# Ubuntu Login Loop

Tags: 14.04

I have a problem logging into Ubuntu under all of my usernames. I have tried many solutions. When I look at my .xsession-errors file, I get the following:

```
xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":o"
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: gnome-session (unity) main process (2292) terminated with status 1
init: unity-settings-deamon main process (2284) killed by TERM signal
init: logrotate main process (2192)killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash) main process (2230) killed by TERM signal
init: xsession-init main process (2201) killed by TERM signal
init: hud main process (2288) killed by TERM signal
init: unity=panel service main process (2299) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: window-stack-bridge main process (2215) killed by KILL signal
```

Comment: Have you tried this question: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)?

Comment: Yes those solutions did not work. I tried the chmod username:username solution to no avail as well as some of the other suggestions on there

Comment: Is it when you try to login you get kicked back to the login screen? Try pressing `ctrl` + `alt` + `F2` to drop to a command shell, login, and then run `sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm` and then `sudo apt-get install lightdm`. If that doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install gdm`.

Comment: I know in your other question you had mentioned installing gdm, were you attempting to install gnome? You could try reinstalling the Unity Desktop Environment.

Comment: @Zacharee1 The lightdm fix did not work. And I already tried the gdm fix and that did not work.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`?

Comment: I've already tried reinstalling lightdm, no effect

Answer (score 1):

## Short Solution

Try to install `linux-headers-generic` and reboot to login again:

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

## Longer Story

Same issue here.  I've tried serveral ways in askubuntu and stackoverflow but in vain.  I write down my solution and hope it will help others.

This issue happens after I use `apt-get purge` to remove all kernels accidentally, then I install `linux-image-generic` and hope everything is ok.  However, I meet this issue after reboot, `.xsession-errors` shows almost same message (just pids are different).

After one hour, I found `linux-headers-generic` is not just header files.  It will also recompile necessary components.  In my case it's nvidia driver.

After install `linux-headers-generic` and reboot, everything is back to normal.