# Stuck in Ubuntu login loop (14.04.5 LTS)

Tags: login, lightdm

This seems to be similar to [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and [Ubuntu Login Loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611734/ubuntu-login-loop) but nothing suggested at either of those two has worked.

I get the login screen. Whether I attempt to log in as myself, another user, or the Guest user, the screen goes black momentarily and returns to the login screen.

Here are the contents of my ~/.xsession-errors:

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2548) terminated with status 1
init: unity-settings-daemon main process (2538) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: logrotate main process (2446) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_ibus_ibus-ui-gtk3.1001.crash) main process (2495) killed by TERM signal
init: xsession-init main process (2535) killed by TERM signal
init: hud main process (2542) killed by TERM signal
init: unity-panel-service main process (2553) killed by TERM signal
init: window-stack-bridge main process (2475) killed by KILL signal
```

As I noted, I tried pretty much everything I found at the referenced questions and nothing has worked - changing permissions and ownerships on .Xauthority and .ICEauthority, installing linux-headers-generic, reconfiguring/uninstalling/reinstalling lightdm, etc.

I'm kind of at a loss on how to proceed. Any ideas?

(Edit; the next day) One thing I hadn't tried was switching to gdm as described at [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). That was no help at **all**. After running dpkg-reconfigure gdm the login screen did not change at all, so I tried rebooting. After that, I got only a couple of seconds of display / active keyboard with each press of ctrl-alt-F2, and it took me about 10 minutes to successfully reconfigure for lightdm. I don't know if that's helpful to anyone reading this....

(Edit) Here is the output of *sudo lshw -c video*:

```
*-display
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:dc000000-dcffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:dd000000-dd07ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
   resources: irq:128 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I can find some info on these drivers with *lsmod*:

```
$ lsmod | grep i915_bpo
i915_bpo             1306624  3 
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915_bpo
drm_kms_helper        151552  2 i915_bpo,nvidia_drm
drm                   360448  5 i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
video                  40960  3 i915_bpo,dell_wmi,dell_laptop

$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm             45056  0 
nvidia_modeset        765952  1 nvidia_drm
drm_kms_helper        151552  2 i915_bpo,nvidia_drm
drm                   360448  5 i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
nvidia              11489280  1 nvidia_modeset
```

So I'm not sure the nvidia video driver belongs?

*modinfo* returns some info about i915_bpo:

```
modinfo i915_bpo
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-47generic/kernel/ubuntu/i915/i915_bpo.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
firmware:       i915/bxt_dmc_ver1.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_dmc_ver1.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_guc_ver6.bin
srcversion:     A0AA67E6671AC7D4B380BAA
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000593Bsv*sd*bc03sc*i*
[etc.]
```

... but there is no info returned from *modinfo* for any of the nvidia.* drivers. I am thinking that the invidia drivers are either corrupted or do not belong, but I'm not sure what to try next. Thanks anyone for any help.

Comment: Those solution didn't in my case also but removing incompatible graphics driver worked just fine. Please check if you have installed any incompatible graphics driver recently.

Comment: I haven't installed any graphics drivers, unless they came with an update pushed to me. Where can I look to make sure?

Comment: Added a couple of edits; see above.

Comment: remove nvidia driver if install any `sudo nvidia-settings --uninstall` and
`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`

Comment: There is no _--uninstall_ option for _nvidia-settings_. However, I ran the _apt-get remove_ command and that seems to have done the trick. Thank you **so** very much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. I'll write an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Incompatible graphics driver causing this problem. Try to remove them using,

`sudo nvidia-settings --uninstall`

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`